# Unable to get the RegisterClientScriptBlock() method to work when passing "true" as last Boolean parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, registerclientscriptblock

Here are the 3 versions tried to include scripts in page:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "JqueryTestFile1",
     "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"jqueryTEST1.js\"></script>", false);

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "JqueryTestFile2",
     "jquery-1.11.0.min.js");

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "JqueryTestFile3",
     "src=\"jqueryTEST3.js\"", true);
```

The First two versions are working fine . However the 3rd one with `"true"` as the last parameter is actually rendering `<![CDATA[` in source code and I can't get this to work.

Why is it rendering CData ? What purpose does it serves in this context? How can I get the third version working  without removing the "true" parameter ?
Below is the html code rendered in browser::

```
<form method="post" action="ScriptsManager.aspx" id="Form1">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryTEST1.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          //<![CDATA[
          src="jqueryTEST3.js"//]]>
     </script>
     <input type="button" value="ClickMe" onclick="DoClick()" />     
</form>
```

Additional Info::

[ Just for avoiding any confusion that all these JS files: `JqueryTest1.js` etc.. are present at proper location in my solution ]. In `JqueryTest3.js`, have only below code:

```
function DoClick(){
alert("Hi");
}
```

If I place this `DoClick()` function in `JqueryTest1.js` file, it works perfectly.

`.aspx` Markup:

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
  <input type="button" value="ClickMe" onclick="DoClick()" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code by the following

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), "JqueryTestFile3",
 "src=\"jqueryTEST3.js\"", true)
```

Remember to add  to your page